# How to get a group of items within multiple lines in regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-re

Example:

```
Online ID:JohnDoe
[+] Country: FR
=========================================
---Played at 2020-05-02 4:00PM
---Played at 2020-03-02 3:00PM
---Played at 2020-01-02 2:00PM
---Played at 2020-01-02 1:00PM
=========================================
```

I want to be able to get the Online ID and all the instances of times the user has played.
I currently have

```
(.*)\sOnline ID:(.*)\s.*\s.*\s.*
```

but I have no clue how to use new lines

Comment: Will there be multiple online ids and played at lines in the file for different users?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Yes, The Online ID does vary and played times do change. The amount of times played is also to be considered

Comment: A regular expression is not always the solution. Some problems are just not that regular that they can be expressed as a regex

Comment: Why don't you just use a loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the following:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: k = r'(?sm)(?:^Online ID:(\w+)$)|(?:^---Played at ([0-9]{4,}-[0-9]{2,}-[0-9]{2,} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2,}[A|P]M$))'

In [3]: data="""Online ID:JohnDoe
   ...: [+] Country: FR
   ...: =========================================
   ...: ---Played at 2020-05-02 4:00PM
   ...: ---Played at 2020-03-02 3:00PM
   ...: ---Played at 2020-01-02 2:00PM
   ...: ---Played at 2020-01-02 1:00PM
   ...: ========================================="""

In [15]: re.findall(k, data, re.MULTILINE)
Out[15]:
[('JohnDoe', ''),
 ('', '2020-05-02 4:00PM'),
 ('', '2020-03-02 3:00PM'),
 ('', '2020-01-02 2:00PM'),
 ('', '2020-01-02 1:00PM')]
```

Here, `s` and `m` enables:

- s modifier: single line. Dot matches newline characters
- m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)

and then the two groups which matter to you:

- `(?:^Online ID:(\w+)$)` to find the user ID
- `^---Played at ([0-9]{4,}-[0-9]{2,}-[0-9]{2,} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2,}[A|P]M$)` to find the time of play

Answer (score 0):

A regex is really not required for this. But if you must, there is no need to make it overly complicated.

Try:

```
import re

text = """
Online ID:JohnDoe
[+] Country: FR
=========================================
---Played at 2020-05-02 4:00PM
---Played at 2020-03-02 3:00PM
---Played at 2020-01-02 2:00PM
---Played at 2020-01-02 1:00PM
========================================="""

l = re.findall(r'(?:Online ID:|Played at )(.*)', text)
print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['JohnDoe', '2020-05-02 4:00PM', '2020-03-02 3:00PM', '2020-01-02 2:00PM', '2020-01-02 1:00PM']
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # start of a non-capture group)
   Online ID:   #  match "Online ID:"
   |            # or
   Played at    # match "Played at "
)               # end of non-capture group
(.*)            # match everything up to but not including the end of line in capture group 1
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ni5DBf/2/)